# Convert a column of set values to a column of individual values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have inherited a table where one column is a comma-separated list of primary keys for a different table:

```
id | other_ids | value
---|-----------|-------
1  | a,b,c     | 100
2  | d,e       | 200
3  | f,g       | 3000
```

I would like to convert this table to one where each `other_id` gets a column of its own:

```
id | other_id
---|---------
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | d
2  | e
3  | f
3  | g
```

However, I cannot think of a way to do this?

The table is > 10 GB in size, so I would like to do this inside the database, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first time post, please be kind.

Try this

```
select id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(other_ids,',',1) as other_id from reverseconcat
UNION
select id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(other_ids,',',2),',',-1) as other_id from reverseconcat
UNION
select id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(other_ids,',',3),',',-1) as other_id from reverseconcat

order by id
```

Although I cant really take any credit. Found this on http://www.programering.com/a/MzMyUzNwATg.html

Unsure how you will go on a huge dataset. Also you will need to add more unions if the other_ids are > 3

Answer (score 2):

If you have the other table, then you can use a `join` and `find_in_set()`:

```
select t.id, ot.pk as other_id
from t join
     othertable ot
     on find_in_set(ot.pk, t.other_ids) > 0;
```